# cURL php is not showing the same result as chrome/firefox does

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am from Bangladesh. When I am using Chrome or Firefox to visit https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000217196656.html, I can see that the default region is set to Bangladesh. So, the contents are loaded accordingly (e.g. Shipping methods). But when I am using the same browser with curl (localhost/test/index.php), the result is not the same. Can anybody help me?

index.php contains the following code

```
<?php
$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000217196656.html');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Comment: Try replicating the headers your browser sends with CURL.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks, but how to do that? Can you help, please!

Comment: Maybe try to set Content-Language

Comment: Content-Language did not help. :-(

Answer (score 0):

In your cUrl, you should send the same data as your chrome browser (the response of the server may depends on headers or even your cookies).

There is a nice tool of [Curl to PHP](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/) which may help you. Go to chrome inspect window and in the network tab, see the sent request, by right clicking the request, you can copy the request as cUrl and use this tool to generate the PHP code for the same HTTP request as your browser does,

So, for example for your mentioned URL in my chrome browser, I got this curl command:

```
curl 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000217196656.html' -H 'authority: www.aliexpress.com' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3' -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed
```

which is translated into the following PHP code:

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000217196656.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authority: www.aliexpress.com';
$headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks. But not executing here in my PC. But when I comment "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);", it works. But the problem for which I posted the question is not solved. The shipping methods did not appear. But when visited by chrome the methods appear. Anyway, did you run it? If yes, then did you get the shipping methods?

Comment: Make sure that the elements you want is in the response HTML of that particular request and it is not loaded by another ajax request afterward